# javascript every function returning false when all items of an array are true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if all items of a javascript array are true using every function:

```
// Iterate over a column of checkboxes
function GetListOfChecks()
{
    var lstChecks = [];
    $('.chkbxq').each(function () {
        lstChecks.push($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked' ? true : false);
    });

    return lstChecks;
}

// Update header checkbox (checked or unchecked)
function UpdateCheckBoxHdr()
{
    var grid = $('#MyGrid').data('tGrid');

    var lstChecks = GetListOfChecks();

    var checked = lstChecks.every(function (v) { v === true; });
    $('.chkbx').attr('checked', checked);
}
```

Then, if all items are true, I put as checked a header checkbox column. Otherwise, I put as unchecked.
The problem I have is below: All items in lstChecks are true but every function is returning false. Why? It should return true instead. Using Chrome inspector I see below values for lstChecks = [true, true, true, true] but it returns false.

Comment: You have a typo. Its actually `lstChecks.every(function (v) { return v === true; });` or simply `lstChecks.every(Boolean);`

Comment: "All items in lstChecks are true" - Have you checked that with `console.log`? I suspect they aren't and that `$(this).attr('checked') === 'checked'` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You should be using `prop('checked')`

Comment: @palaѕн you are right. Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin yes, i checked them. all are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.prop` rather than `.attr` - `.attr` will only give you the status of the checkbox *markup*. You also need to return from the `.every` callback, and simply check `.prop('checked')` (don't use `===`). You should also use `.prop` when setting the `chkbx` at the end:

```js
function GetListOfChecks()
{
    var lstChecks = [];
    $('.chkbxq').each(function () {
        lstChecks.push($(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    return lstChecks;
}

// Update header checkbox (checked or unchecked)
function UpdateCheckBoxHdr()
{
    var grid = $('#MyGrid').data('tGrid');

    var lstChecks = GetListOfChecks();
    var checked = lstChecks.every(v => v);
    $('.chkbx').prop('checked', checked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbxq" onchange="UpdateCheckBoxHdr()">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbxq" onchange="UpdateCheckBoxHdr()">
```

You can also achieve something this trivial very easily without requiring a big library like jQuery:

```js
// Update header checkbox (checked or unchecked)
function UpdateCheckBoxHdr() {
  if ([...document.querySelectorAll('.chkbxq')].every(checkbox => checkbox.checked)) {
    document.querySelector('.chkbx').checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbxq" onchange="UpdateCheckBoxHdr()">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbxq" onchange="UpdateCheckBoxHdr()">
```

Comment: In the expression lstChecks.every(v => v); lambda is not recognized....

Comment: I have replaced lambda with below: stChecks.every(function (v) { return v; }); I suppose it is the same, am i right?

Comment: You can do that too if you want. I prefer the concise version, less code means less surface are for bugs, often. If your development environment doesn't understand ES2015, you might consider upgrading it, 2015 was ages ago in web development terms.

Comment: I have visual studio 2013. Yes it's too old. Time to upgrade.